# angular datatable and datatable plugin is not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs

this will be show as "$scope.RegionData.withDOM is not a function" and also "$scope.RegionData.withButtons is not a function".

and also it will show as " DTColumnBuilder is not defined".

```
  <div ng-controller="RegionController">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
              <table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
           </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

in my controller code is written as calling so api is return in json format.

```
     .controller('RegionController', function( $scope , regionService) {
     $scope.dtOptions = $scope.RegionData
     .withDOM("<'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-4 text-center'B><'col-sm-4'f>>tp")
    .withButtons(
        [
        {extend: 'copy',className: 'btn-sm'},
        {extend: 'csv',title: 'ExampleFile', className: 'btn-sm'},
        {extend: 'pdf', title: 'ExampleFile', className: 'btn-sm'},
        {extend: 'print',className: 'btn-sm'}
        ]
    );
     $scope.dtColumns =
     [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('region_id').withTitle('Region ID'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('region_name').withTitle('Region Name'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('region_code').withTitle('Region Code'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('created_by').withTitle('Created By')

     ];
});
```

an also my index file as to be  written as

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
<!-- App styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/fonts/pe-icon-7-stroke/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/fonts/pe-icon-7-stroke/css/helper.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/styles/style.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="app/JSCRIPT/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/Flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/Flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/Flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/flot.curvedlines/curvedLines.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/jquery.flot.spline/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/datatables.net-buttons-bs/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="app/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/angular-flot/angular-flot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/buttons/angular-datatables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
```

and this div is shown to table.

Comment: Have you installed angular-datatable (bower component)?

Answer (score 0):

You missed to inject **`DTOptionsBuilder`** and **`DTColumnBuilder`** inside your controller.

So install `*angular-datatable*` first. Then in your contoller inject: **`DTOptionsBuilder`** and **`DTColumnBuilder`**.

Ex:

```
 .controller('RegionController', function( $scope , regionService, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) { }
```